# Create a MySQL view that contains a static BIT value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

I'm trying to create a view in MySQL 5.6.24 and I need a `BIT` column. The table I'm creating the view from does not have a `BIT` column.

My `create view` statement goes like this,

```
create view my_view as select id, version, description, 
    b'1' as active from my_table;
```

The view is created however the `active` field is of type `VARBINARY`.

I've also tried `(1) as active` which produces an `INT`. `true as active` also creates an `INT`.

Is there a way to create a `BIT` column in a view like this?

Comment: You mean bit column or boolean?

Comment: Sorry @JuanCarlosOropeza I didn't realize that question was related.

Comment: dont worry,  I didnt neither took me a while find the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot but you can create a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION cast_to_bit (N INT) RETURNS bit(1)
BEGIN
    RETURN N;
END


CREATE VIEW view_bit AS
    SELECT
        cast_to_bit(0),
        cast_to_bit(1),
        cast_to_bit(FALSE),
        cast_to_bit(TRUE),
        cast_to_bit(b'0'),
        cast_to_bit(b'1'),
        cast_to_bit(2=3),
        cast_to_bit(2=2)
```